# Pass combobox value from view to controller using @Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, layout, telerik, persistence

I have a `kendo.combobox()` control on my `Layout.cshtml` page which is a list of projects.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
                            .Name("projects")
                            .Placeholder("select project")
                            .DataTextField("Text")
                            .DataValueField("ID")
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:45%;" })
                            .Filter("contains")
                            .SelectedIndex((int)Session["ProjectNoIndex"])
                            .DataSource(source =>
                            {
                                source.Read(read =>
                                {
                                    read.Action("GetProjectsList", "Home");
                                })
                                    .ServerFiltering(true);
                            })
                )
```

I have a `menu` as well in the `Layout.cshtml` which is created using `@Html.ActionLinks` (one sample below).

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Documents", "Search", "Document", new { projectNo = 1}, new {@id = "send"})</li>
```

Search action in Document controller and most other actions in the application expect the projectNo parameter (entire application works based on the selected project of the user). So, I thought of saving the selected ProjectNo in `Session` but if I do this then users can only work with 1 project even if they open the application in multiple tabs/windows in a single browser (sessions are shared across tabs/windows).

So, I thought of passing the selected ProjectNo using `querystrings`. I tried below, which worked fine except when user right clicks and open's the link in new tab. in such case, below click event does not fire.

```
$('#send').click(function () {
        var x = $("#projects").data("kendoComboBox").selectedIndex;
        var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Document", new { projectNoIndex = "-1" })'
        url = url.replace("-1", x);
        this.href = url;
    });
```

I don't want to restrict user by `oncontextmenu = "return false;"` option either. What are my options here?
Q1: How can I make sure I can pass the selected ProjectNo using `querystring`
Q2: Is there any other alternative to `Session` where I can persist the project information across tabs/windows which can be easily available in the entire application per user, per tab/window.

Comment: Use javascript  to handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist, and update the `href` attribute in the link

Comment: You can handle change event like this: `.Events(e => { e.Change("onChange") })` and create `function onChange(e) { ... }` to update `href` attribute like `$('#send').attr("href", "@Url.Action(...)");`.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this will work fine for the few links that I have in the Layout, but like I said I need the selected ProjectNo available in the entire application (most Actions/Controllers) need this information.

Comment: Then pass it around in each request (and make it a property of your view models)

Comment: You want `ProjectNo` passed from combobox, right? Well, you can use `e.sender.value()` from Kendo combobox with query string: `var url = '@Url.Action("Search", "Document")?projectNoIndex=' + e.sender.value();`.